# RGraphs showing blurry on browser

Tags: apache, blurry, htdocs

I downloaded the rgraphs zip, put it in my apache htdocs folder.
This zip has a demo folder, so I went through several of the demos but the graphs are a little blurry.
On rgraphs website they have the exact same graphs hosted in a demo section, on their page the  graphs are crisp and perfect. In localhost the graph appears a little bigger than on rgraphs website.

I'm using Apache 2.2.24 and starting the server with httpd -k start.

I hope there is something glaringly obvious which I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, my browser was zoomed in, please ignore, ps, to zoom out or in in Chrome hold ctrl and use your mouse roller